# why does using the same c# code to change password in AD in different computer make different speed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory

I used the class in System.DirectoryServices to change password in AD. The code like this:

```
    DirectoryEntry _directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, user, pwd, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
    public bool ChangePassword(string userPath, string newPassword)
    {
        try
        {
            if (userPath != null && _directoryEntry != null)
            {
                _directoryEntry.Path = userPath;
                //Set the password
                _directoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { newPassword });
                _directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Invalid Login or the domain controller is not contactable
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            _directoryEntry.Close();
            _directoryEntry = null;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I executed these codes on different computer. The time spent from several ms to several seconds.

why does the same code executed in different Environment to change password in AD spent different time? I have spent a lot of time in dealing this problem but still no result. Can anybody tell me? Thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: My first thought: is there a difference in network topology between the different machines? Changing AD passwords on a domain controller (for instance) probably takes a lot less time to change than if you were to execute it on a client computer far away from the host.

Comment: Some of the computers are in the same network segment with AD, the others are not. But if the computer can change AD password work quickly, it can change any AD in different network segment quickly. So I think maybe it's not about the network topology, it's about the system environment on the computer. Like some services on one of the computer are up, but the others are not. But i can't find out any obvious differences to make some computers run faster then the others. @ravuya

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it is a simple environment issue. Maybe the network is further away or just slower in general, or it could be that the processor is slower, or just about any number of environmental differences. I would compare some of the key hardware specs. You could also make sure that there are very minimal processes running on each machine to verify that it might not be a conflict from another process.

Comment: The computers I uesd were not busy, and i think the hardware problem won't make such big different speed. I think maybe it's about the system environment. But I still can't find out the problem. @JustinPihony

Answer (score 0):

Well a simple ping report should help you rule out any network related issues. just ping your AD from your different  test machines and observe the response time.

Comment: It can't ping the AD. Some Network equipment intercept the operation.

Comment: then 'ping' AD by asking for just the AD Guid and time the response.

Answer (score 0):

You should really get a network trace and see what's going on. There's alot of moving parts here.

That aside, the way this code is laid out is a bit strange. Why are you creating the `DirectoryEntry` and then changing the `Path` property?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. It is likely because on one computer you are querying the master domain controller directly, and on the other you are querying a read-only domain controller which then has to query the master domain controller. Why? No idea. I just know when I used Wireshark to listen on my AD query traffic, it was always going fast when it was talking to the master domain controller, and slow all the other times. So, I usually include the controller I want in the DirectoryEntry constructor (ie, `LDAP://ip-of-controller/cn=whaerver,ou=2whafsal,dc=etc`).

You can also open a command prompt and run `echo %logonserver%` to check which domain controller you computer will default to (I think).